# Modulus of eigenvalues for overlap matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

### Trying to prove

Reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1244

I was trying to prove a claim in above paper. To summarize, they first define a Hermitian matrix $H(\alpha)$ which depends on a paramter $\alpha$. Since this is Hermitian matrix, all eigenvalues are real, so they first order eigenvalues in increasing order $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2, ...$ and define projection operator $P$ onto the eigenspace with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... \lambda_n$. Multiplicity on $\lambda_n$ is 1, so the projection is well defined.

Then they define a quantity $\gamma$ such that (equation 4)

$$
\gamma = n - Tr(P \tilde{P})
= n - \sum_{i,j}^n|M_{ij}|^2
$$

where $P$ and $\tilde{P}$ are the two projection for two different $\alpha$, $P=\sum_i^n{|\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|}$ and $M_{ij} = \langle \psi_i | \tilde{\psi_j} \rangle$ (equation 5). Here $\psi_i$ ($\psi_j$) are the ith (jth) eigenvector for $H(\alpha)$ ($H(\tilde{\alpha})$)

This is the definitions, and in the line 35 in page 2, there is a claim which says that "since a singular M would imply $\gamma \geq 1$.

I am trying to prove this one.

### Attemped solution

We can define a matrix $X$ as

$$
X = I - MM^{\dagger}.
$$
Then 
$$
\gamma = Tr(X) = n - Tr(M M^{\dagger}) = n - \sum_i{|\mu_i|^2}
$$
Here $\mu$ refers the eigenvalues of $M$.

If $M $ is singular matrix, $\det(M)=0$ and $\det(M) = \prod_i{\mu_i}$ implies that at least one of the eigenvalues of $M$ is zero. 
If $P = \tilde{P}$, $M$ is identity matrix, so all $\mu=1$. 
If $\tilde{P} = (1-P)$, $M$ = 0. 
Considering this exteme case, I guessed that the modulus of all the eigenvalues for matrix $M $ could be less than one. Then since at least one of the eigenvalues is zero, we have

$$
\sum_i{|\mu_i|^2} \leq n-1
$$
so can prove $\gamma \geq 1$

Then my question is for the matrix $M$ defined above (or $MM^{\dagger}$), is it true that the modulus of eigenvalue is less than one?

### Original post

**I keep below the original post only to relate it to the received comments. You don't need to read this part.**

Let $M=M(\lambda)$ be a diagonalizable $n \times n$ matrix which depends on a paramter $\lambda$.

Then assume that for distinct paramters $\lambda_1$ and $  \lambda_2$, we construct a matrix $P$ such that

$$
P_{ij} = \langle u_i^{\lambda_1} |v_j^{\lambda_2}\rangle
$$

where $u_i^{\lambda_1}$ and $v_j^{\lambda_1}$ are the normalized eigenvectors for given paramter $\lambda$.

Also I assume that the multiplicity of all eigenvalues is 1, real number so I can order the eigenvectors by comparing their eigenvalues in increasing order.

For example, if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$,

$$
P_{ij} = \delta_{ij}.
$$

Also, if all of the eigenvectors for two $\lambda$s have no overlap, then

$$
P_{ij} = 0
$$

So for these two extreme cases, we have the modulus of all eigenvalues of matrix $P$ is less than one. My question is, can we say that for arbitrary paramter $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, the modulus of all the eigenvalues of P is less than one?

Comment: I don't understand what $u_i^{\lambda_i}$ is. It is an eigenvector of the matrix $M(\lambda_i)$? if so, then what eigenvalue do we take? $M(\lambda_i)$ can have more than one eigenvalue, and more than one eigenvector. Which one do we take?

Comment: $P_{ij}$ is not well defined, as eigenvectors have no natural order. You could get $P=0$ even for the same parameter: just consider the case of an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors (when it exists), and permute them.

Comment: @5xum $u_i^{\lambda}$ means the ith eigenvector for given $\lambda$ when we order the eigenvalues by increasing order. Also $P_{ij}$ is the inner product of these eigenvectors.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I forgot to mention but we order the values by increasing order (assuming no degenerate eigenvalues).

Comment: Not enough: if $M(\lambda)$ has eigenvalues with multiplicity $>1$, there are infinitely many ways to gen eigenvectors. You have to further assume all eigenvalues are simple, and that you pick a specific eigenvector (you still can change the norm and the orientation).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Then I will assume multiplicity is always 1 for this case so the ordering of eigenvalues is meaningful

Comment: @user42298 Great. Good to know that. But what you say is a **vital** part of the question. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You may also have complex eigenvalues, so to even be able to sort them you have to further assume they are real. That's many assumptions, in the end. And you still haven't said which orientation you pick, as it's not obvious (in your example, it's not really $\delta_{ij}$ but $\pm\delta_{ij}$).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut okay. I edited the question. All eigenvalues have multiplicity 1, and they are real. What do you mean by orientation?

Comment: I mean that if $u$ is an eigenvector, so is $-u$. How do you decide?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'm not sure but I can try this way. First I choose $\lambda_1$ and calculate the eigenvectors. Then all the eigenvectors will be a function of $\lambda$. If there's no singularity in changing $\lambda$, I can continuouslly move from $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_2$ with fixed orientation.

Comment: Is there any motivation to this question or are we just making up stuff as we go along?

Comment: I mean, I don't really mind the making stuff up, that's more or less maths, but this just seems like a poorly thought out idea, not a question.

Comment: @5xum I was trying to prove some claims in paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1244. Starting from equation (1), in the second paragraph in section B, they claim that "a singular M would imply  $\gamma$ >1. I was trying to prove this one.

Comment: @user42298 You should put this in the question too. Here we are trying to guess and we need to ask again and again. Actually, there is a statement in an article, and you are trying to prove it. That's the main point. And after reading part of the article it's not clear that all these assumptions make any sense (and there are somes notations I'm not familiar with, but others could probably help).

Comment: Since there has been no answer in 2 years, and it's now to late to migrate, you may re-asking this on the brand new Materials Modeling stack exchange, where everyone is a practitioner of numerically solving these quantum mechanics problems: https://materials.stackexchange.com/